# Решите в целых числах уравнение ax + b = 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Задача:
>
> Даны числа a и b. Решите в целых числах уравнение ax+b=0. Выведите все
>   целочисленные решения этого уравнения, если их число конечно, выведите
>   слово "NO", если решений нет, выведите слово "INF", если целочисленных
>   решений бесконечно много.
>
> Входные данные:
>   Вводятся два целых числа, не превышающих 30000 по абсолютному
>   значению.
>
> Выходные данные:
>   Выведите ответ на задачу.
>
> Примеры:
>
> 1. Ввод:
>
>    ```
>    6  
>    -2
>    ```
>
>    Вывод:
>
>    ```
>    NO
>    ```
> 2. Ввод:
>
>    ```
>    1
>    -7
>    ```
>
>    Вывод:
>
>    ```
>    7
>    ```

Что не так с кодом? Выдает, что ответ неверный:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
if a!=b:
  if b%a==0:
    print (-b//a)
  else:
     print('NO')
  if b==0:
   print ('INF')
else:
  print ('NO')
```

Comment: Выведите **все** целочисленные решения этого уравнения. В Вашем решении не наблюдаю ни одной процедуры формирующей список

Comment: Список?Думаю это будет не по правилам курса, так как списки мы еще не проходили...

Comment: В чём смысл проверки `if a!=b`?

Comment: Переформулирую. По условию задачи предполагается вывод нескольких решений при их наличии, в Вашем коде не вижу что могло-бы вывести 2-е, 3-е, 4-е и т.д. решения

Comment: Хорошо, не могли бы вы объяснить как правильно решить? Как именно это сделать?

Comment: Если a == b, то решение x = -1, почему вы отбрасываете такой вариант?

Comment: И b==0 надо проверять первым делом, до всего остального, а то сейчас у вас до этого условия вообще программа никогда не доходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if (a == 0 and b == 0):
    print('INF')
elif (a == 0 or (b % a) != 0):
    print('NO')
else: 
    print(int(-b / a))
```

Comment: Вместо `int(-b / a)` лучше `-b // a`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if a == 0 and b != 0:
    print("NO")
elif a == 0 and b == 0:
    print("INF")
elif a != 0:
    if -(b / a) == -(b / a) // 1:
        print(-(b // a))
    else:
        print("NO")
```

У меня такое решение, тоже рабоатет

Answer (score -1):

```
a, b = map(float, input("введите a,b").split())
if a == 0 and b != 0:
print("корней нету")
elif a == 0 and b == 0:
    print("x - любое число")
else:
    if b == 0 and a != 0:
        pass  # хз что тогда
    else:
        x = -b / a
        print("корень уравнения", x)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вы не заметили в вопросе упоминание о целых числах ?